# How to write this example in a more succinct way in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Coming from this list

```
List<Foo> list = new List<Foo>()
{
  new Foo("Albert", 49, 8),
  new Foo("Barbara", 153, 45),
  new Foo("Albert", -23, 55)
};
```

I want to get to a dictionary with the names as key and the first `Foo`-object from the list with that given name as value.

Is there a way to write the logic in a more succinct way using LINQ than what I did here?

```
Dictionary<string, Foo> fooByName = new Dictionary<string, Foo>();

foreach (var a in assignmentIndetifiers)
{
  if (!names.ContainsKey(a.ValueText))
  {
    names.Add(a.ValueText, a);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var dictionary = list.GroupBy(f=>f.Name)
                     .Select(gr=>new { Name = gr.Key, Foo = gr.First() })
                     .ToDictionary(x=>x.Name, x=>x.Foo);
```

I have **assumed** that `Foo` has a property called `Name`, which is the one you want to use as the key for your dictionary. If not so, you should change this correspondingly.

Essentially, we group by the items found in `list` based on the `Name` and then we project the result to an anonymous type of two properties, `Name` and `Foo`, which apparently are associated with the key/value of the dictinary you want and then we call the `ToDictionary` method.

**Update**

As Igor correctly pointed out, you could by pass the whole projection using the `Select` and call immediately the `ToDictionary`

```
var dictionary = list.GroupBy(f=>f.Name)
                     .ToDictionary(gr=>gr.Key, gr=>gr.First());
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `GroupBy()` you can use [MoreLinq's `DistinctBy()`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MoreLinq.Source.MoreEnumerable.DistinctBy/) (available via NuGet):

```
var names = items.DistinctBy(x => x.ValueText).ToDictionary(x => x.ValueText);
```

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? This code definitely works. `DistinctBy()` will keep the first of each duplicate item, just as the OP requires.